Tax, coupon, and zero payment
I am trying to do a very basic task which I guess should be available out of the box. I have read many other comments that do one and not the other,  some are even offering programming with hook altering; I am trying to do this with rules:
In the checkout, when I can add a coupon then it should apply to both item lines and tax line (if there is any, now it does not affect the tax line) and then if the grand total becomes 0 then skip the payment method (currently it stays, it may or may not collect customer's info).
How may I do that?
I am using Drupal 7, Commerce 7.x-1.17, Commerce Coupon 7.x-1.0, and Commerce Coupon Percentage Amount 7.x-1.0-beta7.
